# How can I stitch two pdf pages together with pdfbox (java)?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I can't find the way to do this. What i need is one page as a background and the other one as a foreground.

Comment: Define merge...  One pdf follows another in one document?

Comment: One page follows as a background and the other one as a foreground

Comment: Check out my answer here if you want one more example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33778107/5576194

Answer (score 4):

I've found it!

```
LayerUtility lu = new LayerUtility( doc );
PDXObjectForm form = lu.importPageAsForm( doc2, 0 );
PDPage page = (PDPage) doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get( 0 );
lu.wrapInSaveRestore( page );
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
lu.appendFormAsLayer( page, form, at, "new_layer_name" );
```

Comment: What if the PDF's that you are merging have different page sizes? It destructs the output - tested with a base PDF having a smaller size than the imported layer. Need to set the size or alter the mediabox/cropbox values I'm guessing.