# pdfbox Nup pdf document

Tags: pdfbox

I need to 2-up (A4 to A3 every two A4 pages) a pdf doc. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093408/pdfbox-merge-2-portrait-pages-onto-a-single-side-by-side-landscape-page) and it works (I use the pdfbox answer) but only for the first new page on the newly created doc. The problem is that when use a loop to add more new pages then it throws an error "Optional group (layer) already exists: left" in the `layerUtility.appendFormAsLayer(outPdfPage, formPdf1, afLeft, "left");`

UPDATE:
I replaced "left" with "left" + i to have left1,left2 etc but the result is a not well responsive pdf file after 100-200 pages. It is very difficult to navigate pages.

Comment: I did it this way ("left"+i) and it works but the result is a not well responsive pdf file. Also I have already use some ready tools out there but they are very very slow after some pages

Comment: Fonts are ok. I made 10 files 100 pages each. Then I merged them. 10 times worst. I followed the same process with a ready tool. Everything ok!!! It seems that the previous method with LayerUtility adds too many layers than a pdf reader can handle.